# Quotient of $S_4$ by a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is this true?

> >
>   Quotient of $S_4$ by a normal subgroup of order 4 is Abelian ?

As the group is of order 4!/4=6, so it is either $S_3$ or $\mathbb Z_6$. how to decide? please help.

Comment: Hint: Does $S_4$ have an element of order $6$?

Comment: If it is abelian, then it is cyclic of order $6$. What could map to a generator?